# Execution failed for task ':kotlin-source:compileKotlin'

Tags: corda

I tried to run the cordapp-example from the command prompt. But when I input the "gradlew.bat deployNodes" command, I got the error as below.

---

```
Execution failed for task ':kotlin-source:compileKotlin'.    
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':kotlin-source:compileClasspath'.  
Could not determine artifacts for org.jolokia:jolokia-war:1.3.7       
Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jolokia/jolokia-war/1.3.7/jolokia-war-1.3.7.war'.   
Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jolokia/jolokia-war/1.3.7/jolokia-war-1.3.7.war'.        
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

---

I had done the "keytool -importcert" command to import the certificate of jolokia-war into java cacerts, but the error was still there.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: I am using jdk-8u172.

Comment: Are you able to access https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jolokia/jolokia-war/1.3.7/jolokia-war-1.3.7.war from a browser on the machine where you are building the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the compilation failed because your machine was unable to download the resource at this location: `https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jolokia/jolokia-war/1.3.7/jolokia-war-1.3.7.war`.

This URL works for me and I was able to download the resource. You are most likely behind a firewall or otherwise unable to download this resource. You need to make your machine able to access this resource to compile and deploy the node.